# Как сделать гравитацию и тросы на Питоне 2d игра

Tags: python, pygame

Если что я новичок.
Хочу сделать простенькую игру на Питоне используя PyGame. Персонаж (спрайт вроде называется) должен передвигаться используя тросы по которым от будет как бы раскачиваться. Так вот как сделать адекватную гравитацию и сами тросы тоже.

Comment: вероятно, следует браться за игры, когда уже перестанешь быть новичком

Comment: Нужен физический движок - либо самому написать, либо взять что-то готовое. Из готового можно посмотреть pybox2d и pymunk

Comment: @Эникейщик не согласен, с программирования каких-то простых игр и стоит начинать программирование.

Comment: @insolor ну так тросы и гравитация уже и не очень простая игра

Comment: @Эникейщик гравитация - это просто, даже для новичка, даже без физического движка) Тросы, сложнее, но тоже реализуемо. Особенно, если нужна не 100% правдоподобная физическая симуляция гибкого троса, а просто симуляция жесткого качающегося маятника.